# Java - Extend class with enum

Tags: java, class, enums, extends

I have a class `BaseNumber` with a `protected static enum Base`, and another class `ArithmeticBaseNumber extends BaseNumber`. 
I can access the `Base` enum from `BaseNumber`, however not from `ArithmeticBaseNumber`. 
Is there a way to access the enum? 
Thank you!

Edit - The code:

```
public class BaseNumber {
    protected static enum Base {
        X, Y, Z
    }
}
public class ArithmeticBaseNumber extends BaseNumber {}
```

The problem is that `BaseNumbe.Base.X` works fine, however `ArithmeticBaseNumber.Base.X` gives "The type ArithmeticBaseNumber.Base is not visible" error.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code? It'll make it easier to see the problem here.

Comment: @MCEmperor I added the code.

Comment: It follows the rules of `protected` members. But why do you want to access the constant via `ArithmeticBaseNumber.Base.X`? It’s still the same constant as when being accessed via `BaseNumber.Base.X`. There is no advantage in using the other expression.

Comment: @Holger I want to deny the programmer from using `BaseNumber` class at all.

Comment: You can’t deny using a public class. Besides that, using `ArithmeticBaseNumber.Base.X` still implies using `BaseNumber`, as `Base` is a nested type of `BaseNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support the inheritance of static members, a static member is callable on a class in which it has been created.

Answer (score 0):

It can be accessed. Try below example.

```
package com.example.demo.enumexample;

public class BaseNumber {
protected static enum Base{
FIRST("first"),
SECOND("second"),
THIRD("third");
String httpMethodType;
Base(String s) {
    httpMethodType = s;
}
public String getHTTPMethodType() {
    return httpMethodType;
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base baseNum = Base.FIRST;
    System.out.println(baseNum);
}
}
```

And in ArithmeticBaseNumber.java

```
package com.example.demo.enumexample;

import com.example.demo.enumexample.BaseNumber.Base;

public class ArithmeticBaseNumber extends BaseNumber{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base baseNum = Base.FIRST;
    System.out.println(baseNum);
}
}
```

Output will be :

> FIRST

In your example code,

```
package com.example.demo.enumexample;

public class BaseNumber {
protected static enum Base{
    X, Y, Z;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base baseNum = Base.X;
    System.out.println(baseNum);
}
}
```

And

```
package com.example.demo.enumexample;


public class ArithmeticBaseNumber extends BaseNumber{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base baseNum = Base.X;
    System.out.println(baseNum);
}
}
```

Output will be :

> X

Answer (score 0):

The one enum type you're defining is `BaseNumber.Base` and not `ArithmeticBaseNumber.Base` nor simply `Base`.

So just reference it by its proper name `BaseNumber.Base`, and everything is fine.

You can (but probably shouldn't) make the simple name `Base` work by importing:

```
    import mypackage.BaseNumber.Base;
```

Caveat: if you want to use the short name, I'd typically recommend moving the `Base` enum out into its own file - to me, the dotted syntax is an important reminder that we're talking about some internal element of `BaseNumber`.

As a similar case, for readability reasons, I always stay with `Map.Entry` instead of `Entry` (unclear that it's related to `Map`s) or `HashMap.Entry` (plain wrong, `Entry` isn't part of `HashMap`).